# Storage capacity of dictionary and want to store huge data into dictionary in python

Tags: python, memory, dictionary

I want to **store huge data into a dictionary** in python. Huge data may be around **21 GB**. I wrote a snippet to do so. Storing the **integer values** inside the dictionary.

**Code:**

```
import timeit
import sys
dicts = {}
print "\n***Building dict..."
start = timeit.default_timer()
for j in range(0,5):
    for i in range(0,1000000):
        dicts[''+str(j)+str(i)] = i
        print str(i) + '-' + str(j)
        print "Size : ", sys.getsizeof(dicts)/1024/1024, " MB"
print "Total time of build dict", timeit.default_timer() - start
```

During runtime, when  I reached the **size using** `**getsizeof(dicts)**` around **1.2GB**, it **fails to** store the values in dictionary but **doesn't show any error**. Does **Dictionary has** some **capacity to store** the data?

So, the question is how can I store huge data into the dictionary?

**NOTE: Doesn't require to store the data in files or databases**. because I want to retrieve the **key, value pair very fast**.

Comment: How much memory does your system currently have?

Comment: Do you have 21GB+ of memory? If you're storing 21GB of data, you need at least that amount of memory (plus the overhead of Python, not sure how much that is, but it's probably a quite a bit as well)... You *could* use swap space, but I doubt that would be faster than a SQL database...  What problem are you trying to solve anyway? I suspect this is the wrong solution for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Swapping is the worst possible option, as databases for most part come with mechanism that way better utility of IO and ram to provide much greater performance. So you will need ram to keep all the data you want + more for index of it + some for overheads + more for other things running.

Comment: @ user2097159 : I have 4GB of RAM in my machine.

Comment: With only having 4GB of RAM in your machine it doesn't suprise be that  your dict is only about 1.2GB  After the OS other processes and overhead that sounds about right.  You can't store more data in a dict than you have of memory so writing to a file/Database is your best/only option

Comment: If you only had a bucket that held a volume of a liter, would you expect to be able to hold 50 liters of water in the bucket?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit of the size of a Python dict depends on the free memory the OS makes available. The problem is that as a dict grows (resizes) it has to copy itself to redistribute the keys so when the dictionary get really huge this process can start to require a lot more memory than is actually available.